# Rails 7 submit button redirects to referer path with token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 7 with Turbo in some part of the app where I'm trying to build a file upload mechanism. The idea is that user in the `profile` page could upload file which is not saved anywhere but is encoded into Base64 string and sends this file to an external service.

What I did is:

```
# routes
profile GET                /profile(.:format)             profile#show
kyc_document_upload POST   /kyc_document_upload(.:format) profile#kyc_document_upload

# profile_controller.rb
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def kyc_document_upload
    @file = FileRead.open(params[:file])
    body = Base64.encode64(@file)
    ExternalApi.user.sent_missing_docs(body)
  end

# views/profile/show.html.erb
<%= form_tag(kyc_document_upload_path, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Surprisingly it doesn't work. After file was chosen and clicks the `Save changes` button (btw no idea why `submit` has that name) it reloads the profile page with token as a query params - `http://localhost:3000/profile?authenticity_token=OOCkRyzdJK-vCu9I8ovWJtollyk5hLKDllIcsl_SRSlFYYoA9CsopIiL9EhPIfu97LUTXN6XPr9pRRl8xd-8gA&commit=Save+changes` and does not hit the `kyc_document_upload` endpoint at all.

The expected behaviour would be:

- choose file to be attached
- click submit (hit the `kyc_document_upload` endpoint)
- not reload the page
- show green (or whatever) as a confirmation

Since it doesn't work out of the box here what did I missed (except the green mark) ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! turns out the form_tag was wrapped into `<form></form>` at the top of page so Rails automatically delete the input submit tag for the submit button.